# Create method not adding multiple results

Tags: laravel, foreach, laravel-5.4, mass-assignment

I have a blade template, where the user can add multiple options `option[]`, through a dynamic drop down.

**If I output the array, it shows (correct):**

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => "sdfsdfsdf"
  1 => "sdfsdfsdflj"
  2 => ""
]
```

The above input relate to the column `point` within the `action_points` table.

**Model for the above table:**

```
 protected $fillable = [
        'audit_score_id', 'point', 'actioned',
    ];

    public function audit()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(AuditScore::class);
    }
```

The table has a `belongsTo` relationship, and so each row has a `audit_score_id` column.

As well as store the `point` information, I want to store the `audit_score_id`.

When I use the below function, only 1 empty row is saved within the table:

```
$actions = $request->get('option');

$item = array();
foreach ($actions as $action) {
    $item = ([
        'point' => $action,
   ]);
}

$audit = AuditScore::find($id);
$audit->actionPoints()->create($item);
```

**Saved row:**

```
id  audit_score_id  point   actioned
5         32                    0
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have a bug, your code actually has only one item, which is the last `$action`. Change how you fill your array.

```
$actions = $request->get('option');

$item = array();
foreach ($actions as $action) {
    // this notation is for pushing items to the array
    $item[] = [
        'point' => $action,
   ];
}

$audit = AuditScore::find($id);
$audit->actionPoints()->create($item);
```